# What is type for file upload Event in react typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, types

I want to add type in code but I don't know about what type can I use

```
const handleFileChange = (e: any>) => {
setCollect({
  ...collect,
  [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0],
 });
};
```

I won't use any, how can I fix it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Proper typing for this event is the following:

`React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`

It will let you access `e.target.files`.

Comment: it alert " Object is possibly 'null' "

Comment: Just check if e.target is not null at the beginning of the function.

Comment: how can I do this

Comment: if(e.target === null) return; at the beginning of you function.

Comment: it not work, it alert same " Object is possibly 'null' "

Comment: What is the exact 'Object' are you talking about? Which property gives you this error?